# Magento 2: Why my static content for languages are not generated after migration?

Tags: magento2, css, migration, deploy

I made a **backup** of **Magento 2** and copied the whole site to another host. I extracted files and created a database. Now I get no CSS loaded. They all are "missing".

First I thought that it was caching or rewrite module problem, but now I found that if I deploy the static content, only en_US is deployed, although my default is ru_RU (this is where the CSS files are attempted to be loaded from).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main command it's below that will deploy the **en_US** and **ru_RU**:

```
php -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US ru_RU
```

If doesn't work run these commands:

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"

chmod -R 775 pub/static/ var/ pub/media/ &&
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ ;
php -r "opcache_reset();"
mage deploy:mode:set developer;
mage setup:static-content:deploy en_US ru_RU;
mage cache:flush &
mage indexer:reindex &
mage setup:upgrade &&
mage setup:db-data:upgrade &&
mage dev:source-theme:deploy &&
chmod -R 775 pub/static/ pub/media/ var/
```

Comment: php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US ru_RU -f

Answer (score 1):

You need to run deploy command for all languages as below.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US ru_RU
```

Answer (score 0):

Please run following ssh command on the magento directory. Please, check your directory(using pwd command ) before running any command.

1- `rm -rf var/*`

2- `rm -rf pub/static/*`

3- `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

4- `php -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US ru_RU`

5- `chmod -R 777 var pub/static`

6- `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`