# Deployment does no create /js folder with main.js

Tags: static-content, deploy

During the process of updating my Magento2 website, the console commands fail to create my `main.js` file, and shows me this error  `static/frontend/website/default/pt_PT/js/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

I've tried to flush the cachem, re-index, and update

```
>Clean cache
 php bin/magento cache:clean

>Upgrade
 php bin/magento setup:upgrade

>Deploy
 php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
 php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy pt_PT -f 

>Reindex
 php bin/magento indexer:reindex

>Compile
 php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

But it did nothing basically, because i always end up getting the `404 cannot find main.js` file.
This might be causing some other problems in my magento website.

I've already checked [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176530/magento-2-why-my-static-content-for-languages-are-not-generated-after-migration) and [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/143133/magento2-after-deploy-in-another-language-the-generated-js-translation-json-is)

Comment: Where the main.js file is located in your theme or module?

Comment: The main.js is located on my app folder, so i'm guessing my theme. i'm fairly new to magento sorry!

Comment: Let me know full path to the js file, please - probably, the issue in the wrong path.

Comment: the full relative path is `app/design/frontend/website/default/Magento_Theme/web/js/main.js`

Comment: Try to place the file in app/design/frontend/website/default/web/js/main.js (without Magento_Theme folder) and after regenerating static files it should be available by pub/static/frontend/website/default/pt_PT/js/main.js

Comment: I think the folder you told me to it move to does not exists, is it supossed to me to create it ?

Comment: Yep, just create them.

Comment: Just did , error still happens ...

Answer (score 0):

First, check if var/ and pub/ folders have proper permissions, then run below commands in same order:

- rm -rf generated
- php bin/magento indexer:reindex
- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento setup:di:compile
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
- php bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: Didn't work, the problem still persists.

Comment: rm -rf  /pub/static/ and then try. Also, if possible call me on skype pankaj.damco!